# SQL Query to fetch latest messages based on latest timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table : `msg_status`, which stores details of the messages sent from application to another.
If a message fails then the status is set to "`ERR`". There is a retry mechanism that automatically retries sending the Errored messages. On retry the messages could succeed (`OUT`) or again Error out.

I need to frame a `SQL` query that displays only those messages with its latest message status as `ERR`.

Hence my query should display `message ID B456` and not `A123`.

I have framed the below query :

```
select a.* from msg_status a where a.message_status = 'ERR' and a.id in 
(select b.id from msg_status b where b.message_status = 'OUT' group by b.id having max (a.timestamp) > max (b.timestamp) )
```

The query works, but is pretty slow. Could you please let me how can i tune this query for faster retrieval of data. If you can suggest any alternate query, i am okay with that as well.

Below is the table :

```
ID   Message_Status  Timestamp

A123     OUT         05-10-17 11:00

B456     ERR         05-10-17 10:00

B456     OUT         05-10-17 9:00

A123     ERR         05-10-17 8:00

B456     ERR         05-10-17 7:00

C789     OUT         05-10-17 6:00
```

Database : **Oracle**

Comment: Based on what you wrote, you could just retrieve where status = Err and not exists any row for the same id with greater timestamp, no?

Comment: @stephen.vakil, i am not sure that would work, as a message could go from ERR to OUT and then might ERR again. Hence, i am looking for the latest timestamp and not greater than timestamp of the ERR message.

Comment: I don't follow.  If there are no records for the id with a greater timestamp then you are on the latest record.

Comment: @stephen.vakil - i have edited the table accordingly, to include the scenario that I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
       ,message_status
       ,time_stamp
from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by message_status order by time_stamp desc) as rn
from mytable tb1
where tb1.message_status = 'ERR') tb1
where tb1.rn = 1
```

I think this should work, but I don't know if the performance is any better than yours. This should always pick the latest `message_status = 'err'`

Answer (score 0):

All you want is records where the status is ERR and no later record for the same ID exists

```
select * from
msg_status a where message_status = 'ERR' and not exists
(select b.id from msg_status b where a.id = b.id and b.timestamp> a.timestamp);
```

Returns only the `B456` record from `2017-05-10 2017-05-10 10:00:00.0`

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e55e/1)